# jtable cant display filter request from jcombobox

Tags: java, sql

I have an inventory list of items that can be categorized. the category types are in a database table and jcomboCategory displays them: code is a follows:

```
try{
    String sql = "select Category from ItemCategories";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
    String cat = rs.getString("Category");
    jcomboCategory.addItem(cat);
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally{
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            }
        }
```

I want a situation such that when a category type is selected from 'jcomboCategory',inventory table should filter records to only display records of that chosen category.this is what I have written so far but nothing happens when a select a category from 'jcomboCategory'.

```
private void combo_categoryPopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                            
    String cat= jcomboCategory.getSelectedItem().toString();
    try{
    String sql ="select * from Inventory where CATEGORY='"+cat+"'";  
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    inventoryList.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }finally{
                try{
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
   // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners